# How to use tensorflow grappler?

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to optimize my tensorflow model serving performance by applying grappler, *I'm working on a C++ tensorflow-serving service*.
AFAIK, I should do the grappler stuff after `LoadSavedModel`. But I'm not sure what exactly should I do, should I write the `op` optimization myself or I just call the API?
I've Google searched for quite a while and didn't see problem-solving post or code snippets.

Could you give me any advice or code example for this?

Answer (score 3):

I've found an answer by searching the tensorflow code base.

```
     tensorflow::grappler::GrapplerItem item;
     item.fetch = std::vector<std::string>{output_node_};
     item.graph = bundle_.meta_graph_def.graph_def();
     tensorflow::RewriterConfig rw_cfg;
     rw_cfg.add_optimizers("constfold");
     rw_cfg.add_optimizers("layout");
     auto new_graph_def = bundle_.meta_graph_def.mutable_graph_def();
     tensorflow::grappler::MetaOptimizer meta_opt(nullptr, rw_cfg);
     meta_opt.Optimize(nullptr, item, new_graph_def);
```

By adding the code lines above, I got my GraphDef-Serialized-Filesize reduce from 20MB to 6MB, so surely it did the pruning. But I found the session.Run() cost more time than before.

============
update:
The usage above is incorrect. The default setting optimizes graph with grappler, and runs when load saved models. You could learn the right usage by review the `LoadSavedModel` related codes.

Comment: Can you share any other tips? I am trying to save an optimized graph and reuse it later on